# Chrome Notifications Stop Working

Tags: google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging

My team's app uses GCM to send notifications.  The notification system works well, but we have noticed that situations arise where a user will stop receiving notifications without an apparent cause.  When the user toggles the "send notifications" setting in Chrome in an effort to reset the notifications, we have noticed that the user will register with GCM with a different registration ID.

Has anyone experienced this type of behavior?  Is it possible that the user's registration ID is expiring?  Thanks!

Comment: What response did your app server receive in these instances where a user did not receive the notification?

Comment: Yes, it seems almost always the user registers with a new ID. I just keep the last 100 or so registrations for the user in an array on the user, and send notifications to all of them.